# Query to delete records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following fields. My requirement is to delete the records from the table when 
1. The Flag is set to 'No'
2. For a title, in one record if the flag is set to 'No' and in another record if it is set to 'Yes'. Delete both the records. For example TH-123, In 1st record the flag is set to 'No' and in 4th record flag is set 'Yes' Delete both the records.
3. For a title, in one record if the flag is set to 'No' and in another record if it is set to ''(space). Delete both the records. For example TH-344. Delete both the records.

```
   Title                        Flag     

    TH-123                        No
    TH-344                        
    TH-543                        No
    TH-123                        Yes
    Th-344                        No
    Th-098                        Yes
    Th-876                        Yes
    Th-098                        Yes
    Th-512                        No
```

so now i am expecting a result, with the following records.

```
    Th-098                        Yes
    Th-876                        Yes
    Th-098                        Yes
```

I have done this with 2 queries.

```
update temp1 set [flag] = 'No' WHERE Title IN 
(SELECT Title FROM temp1 where [flag] = 'No')

delete from temp1 where [flag] = 'No'
```

Is it possible to do with a single query. If so please let me know or any other better procedure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete from temp1 
where 
    Title IN 
        (SELECT Title FROM temp1 where [flag] = 'No')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```
delete from t1
from temp1 t1
  inner join temp2 t2 on t1.Title = t2.Title
where t2.[flag] = 'No'
```